# Difference between chaining promises vs values in .then methods?

Tags: javascript

for a while, I thought the only way to chain `.then()` statements was to return a promise from the .then method. e. g.:

```js
    asyncFunc()
       .then(res => asyncFunc2()) // returns a promise
       .then(res => doSmth())
```

But now I figured out that you can actually also return a plain old value from the .then function and it also works:

```js
    const build = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("Hallo")
      }, 100)
    })
    
    build()
        .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res + " I'm";
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res + " Peter");
      })
```

**Is there a difference between the two in terms of how and when they are executed?**

Comment: No, but returning a non-Promise can make the code more confusing than it needs to be. If something isn't asynchronous, easier to use synchronous code without chaining `.then`s

Comment: Assuming none of your promises (first case) get rejected, then no - there is no difference. Returning a plain value `x` is the same as returning `Promise.resolve(x)`.

Comment: I agree but the stripe docs are using this coding style quite heavily. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#create-subscription This had me wondering if there was a purpose to it. Probably just trying to be cool. Or just to catch all errors that may arise in the statements.

Comment: When learning by example it happens that one might think a specific syntax is mandatory. Please note that in your initial example can be simplified. 1. since you are not using `res` you can replace it with `()`. 2. assuming `asyncFunc2` and `doSmth` don't need (ignore) parameters, you can simplify it to: `asyncFunc().then(asyncFunc2).then(doSmth);`
While the second might oversimplify, the first simplification actually makes your code more readable, since the reader does not wonder what happens with `res`.

Answer (score 2):

Each `.then()` method call returns a promise, if the return value of the callback function is also a promise, then the promise returned by the `.then()` method call gets resolved to that promise, meaning its fate will now depend on what happens to the promise returned by the callback function. It will settle when the promise returned by the callback function settles.

On the other hand, if you return a non-promise value, then that value is implicitly wrapped in a promise and passed to the next `.then()` method call, if there's any. If you don't return anything from the callback function, the promise returned by the `.then()` method will resolve with the value of `undefined`.

In first code example, as you are returning `asyncFunc2()` from the callback function of first `.then()` method, the promise returned by it will get resolved to the promise returned by `asyncFunc2()`.

In the second code example, `res + " I'm"` will be implicitly wrapped in a promise and then passed to second `then()` method.

Comment: Can you add a link to the spec?

Comment: @htho link to what exactly?

Comment: @htho [Promise/A+ specs](https://promisesaplus.com/) or what?

Comment: Yes. This answer is good. But it would be better if the key parts would be backed by links to the according sections in the spec. Especially the fact, that a Promise can not resolve to a Promise. The spec does not say that a primitive value will "implicitly" wrapped, but the promise will be fulfilled with the value.

Comment: @htho _"that a Promise can not resolve to a Promise"_ - i never said that promise can't resolve to a promise. _"The spec does not say that a primitive value will "implicitly" wrapped, but the promise will be fulfilled with the value"_ - if you return a non-promise value from the callback function of `then()` method, how can a promise returned by the `then()` method resolve with that value? Returning a non-promise value is same as returning `Promise.resolve(v)`, where `v` is the non-promise value.

Comment: You are right about the second part I got off-track with my thoughts. Although you did not say it directly, the important implication (and lesson) is that a promise will not resolve to a promise. Once *I* understood that, I finally was able to escape callback hell and also to competently use async/await.